# DBI::dbWriteTable, invalid multibyte string

Tags: sql, encoding, odbc, dbi

Large dataset imported from MS Access Database, data is then subset by date and exported to SQL Database.

Exporting via sqlsave command works just fine, however due to the size of the dataset (over 500,000 rows with 73 variables) it is not suitable.

Trying to write the data using odbc generates the following error: Error in nchar(as.character(x)) : invalid multibyte string, element 62220

From using google and browsing Stackoverflow I have seen that this error usually relates to non standard characters within the data.

I have used dplyr to remove all non standard characters before trying to write the table to SQL, same error.

I then exported the file to csv using the UTF-8 encoding and brought it back in using UTF-8 encoding before trying to write the table to SQL, same error.

Finally I tried a method of specifyinh maximum column length and the structure of each column formatted to varchar(255), float or date. Same error.

```
library(odbc)
library(RODBC)
library(DBI)
library(data.table)

setwd("E:/BUS_INSIGHTS/David r scripts/PUNE_Claims")

odbcCEDBS0233 <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), dsn = "CEDBS0233")
CEDBS0233 = odbcConnect("CEDBS0233")

PUNE <- dbConnect(drv = odbc::odbc(), .connection_string = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; Dbq=E:/Motor/Data/ZC Combined/2018/1812/ZC Combined Pune.accdb")

PUNE <- subset(PUNE, DATE_OF_LOSS > as.Date("2009-01-01"))

require(dplyr)
clean <- PUNE %>%
mutate_all(funs(gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", .)))

DBI::dbWriteTable(con = odbcCEDBS0233,
              name = SQL('PUNE_Claims'),
              value = clean,
              overwrite=TRUE,)
```

I've tried various other methods, such as writing the csv directly to SQL (sadly our SQL server will not allow this). Using Regex, and other things I have now forgotten.

Have completely hit a brick wall here, I have no idea why sqlsave happily uploads the data and odbc flat out refuses to.

I cannot find how to locate element 62220 to see what is wrong, but with dplyr cleaning out any bad characters there should be no issue.

I'm in your hands, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Had a similar problem reading a csv and writing to a database using ODBC. Solved it by reading in the data with `tbl <- data.table::fread(path_to_csv, encoding="Latin-1")`.  After that, `dbwriteTable(con, "schema.table", tbl)` worked (where `con` is the ODBC connection object).

You can do `dbDataType(con, tbl[, 1])`,  `dbDataType(con, tbl[, 2])`, etc. to go through the data.table columns one at a time and determine which ones are causing problems.  If it's column 3 and the error is for element (row) 62220, use `tbl[62220, 3]` to see the offending text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're aware which column is causing this problem, you can go for following

```
x <- iconv(x,"WINDOWS-1252","UTF-8")
```

Otherwise, just run a loop through every column to convert it to `UFT-8`

```
df[,sapply(df,is.character)] <- sapply(
    df[,sapply(df,is.character)],
    iconv,"WINDOWS-1252","UTF-8")
```

This should solve the problem.