# How to solve error **Error in nchar(rownames(m)) : invalid multibyte string, element 1**?

Tags: r, lda

## Create document-term matrix

```
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(docs, control = params)
```

> **Error in nchar(rownames(m)) : invalid multibyte string, element 1**

Anyone who knows how to tackle this error?
Working in Rstudio

Comment: Please read how to create a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 4):

```
Sys.setlocale( 'LC_ALL','C' )
```

In R studio apply this code .. It will refresh the locale .. worked for me many times.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I despise it because of this error, but it works for me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

This happens when your input text isn't UTF-8 encoded. You can read about character encoding [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding).

Another good reference is [this](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

I've found that the best way to handle these issues is to use `stringr::str_conv`.

```
mydocs <- c("doc1", "doc2", "doc3")

stringr::str_conv(mydocs, "UTF-8")
```

Where you have non-UTF-8 characters, you'll get a warning, but the character vector that comes out the other side will be usable.

Do that to your `docs` vector before calling `DocumentTermMatrix.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error while trying to write a data frame to a SQL server table. This function helped me, I used it to remove all non-UTF8 characters from a data frame before writing it to the server. It's built off another post, linked below.

```
# Create a function to convert all columns to UTF-8 encoding,
# dropping any characters that can't be converted.
df_convert_utf8 <- function(df_data){

  # Convert all character columns to UTF-8
  # Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54633054/dbidbwritetable-invalid-multibyte-string
  df_data[,sapply(df_data,is.character)] <- sapply(
    df_data[,sapply(df_data,is.character)],
    iconv,"WINDOWS-1252","UTF-8",sub = "")
  
  return(df_data)
}
```

Example usage:

```
  # Convert all character strings to UTF8, removing any characters we can't use
  df_chunk <- df_convert_utf8(df_chunk)
```